# Double entry tourist visa Thailand in Laos - flight ticket /20,000B required?

Tags: visas, money, thailand

I'm in Thailand now with a single entry tourist visa from Penang. I'm planning to obtain a double entry tourist visa for Thailand in Laos. I'll be traveling by land in and out. First question: Do I need a flight ticket to apply for the visa? And then when should it be dated? If I get a double entry, of course I'll be leaving and coming back (by land). And, do I need to show my flight ticket to enter Thailand with this visa? And one last question: Do I really need to travel with an extra 20,000B in cash to show at the border?

Answer (score 3):

Can't help with the Thai Embassy in Laos requirements, as each Thai Embassy does things a little differently.  You might try perusing the Thaivisa.com forum, as there are numerous threads regarding obtaining visa in SE Asia for Thailand, plus plenty of knowledgeable expats to answer your post.

The 20,000 baht rule is randomly enforced.  I have seen folks asked to show the cash at both airports and land crossings.  Most have been people that were slovenly dressed by Thai standards, worn out pants & tanktops, dreads, barefoot, etc.  Dress neatly and you will likely pass straight through. Also flashing a couple of major credit cards helps if you do get asked